# What's the meaning of enqueue_input and globe_step/sec in the tensorboard and how to interpret that figure?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, tensorboard

I used the tensorboard to visualize my training process. The loss is what I want, but I still get two other scalars. One is queue_input and the other is global_step/sec. What's the meaning of them? Is global_step/sec related to the training speed? And what about enqueue_input?
[enqueue_input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zFai1.png)

Answer (score 0):

`global_step/sec` is the number of training steps evaluated per second. This is dependent on a variety of things, but most significantly by the batch size, network complexity, and your computer's processing power.

According to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43416234/7093605), the `enqueue_input` graph seems to be indicating the `num_elements_in_the_queue/capacity_of_the_queue` at each step.